# Android Gallery View and adapter getView gets called many time

Tags: android, image, view, gallery, adapter

I have a Gallery, which has an adapter connects to it.  In the getView method, i have a custom layout, so that I can i have image and caption displayed together

The image is downloaded from an URL, which is done asynchously, and working as expected.

Currently i make each item to fill the screen, so i only have one item display at a time, basically i want to make it like a slide show.

let me be clear, currently i have an activity, and it only has one View, which is a Gallery.

problem occurs when  I am swiping, the image bounces and stays at the same image.  i need to swipe many times, hard, and long swipe, then i can get to next image.

i put a debug message in my custom adapter in the getView(), it seems getView is getting called many times (4 times),  and position being passed is either the current position or the previous one, which explains why i am stuck at the same screen.

if i remove the remote downloading image part, or just use a static image form the phone, i don't have any more issues, in fact, the getView only gets called once, with correct position.

i am very frustrated, not sure what the problem is, could it be because i am downloading image asynchously, which will cause the image to update which causes getView to get called again to redraw itself?
i am not sure..

please help

Comment: we need a code sample to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a bug with gallery. Listviews will scroll nicely regardless of data being updated asynchronously. However, the gallery is just not coded up to par with the listview

When the gallery tries to update a visible view (due to your image loading callback) this view will "snap" back to the focused position. If you are changing the view in any way when it is scrolling it will snap. This is likely why you have to scroll hard to get away from the current view. It is trying to perform a callback on your view and only scrolling fast will prevent the callback from occurring before you move away from that view.

I've reported this bug a while ago here:
[Android Issues](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15526)
There are a few workarounds posted in there you can try if you are set on using a Gallery.

Unfortunately it hasn't gained attention from the Android developers. 
It seems the issue is caused with views being set to "wrap_content" and the gallery having to remeasure/redraw its views

I have since migrated away from using the gallery and instead use a ViewPager. It is much easier to manage and you don't have to worry about this problem. This has been a known problem with the Gallery since the gallery was first introduced. I have no idea if this was fixed in any of the newer Android versions (3.x/4.x). As of 2.3.7 it is not fixed.

Comment: Thank you sir...you just saved me another day...i have been debugging for 2 days.  can you recommend me any other View that can archive slide show..does ViewPage lets you see the "transition" between current item and next item?  I was just looking at ViewFlipper, i am not sure if ViewPage is better or ViewFliper suits my need...

Comment: Use a ViewPager. It will let you "slide" nicely between views one at a time. It pre-loads the next and (depending where you start) previous views so that transitions are seamless and smooth.

Comment: Too bad the i can't support the API level of ViewPager..also..what do you think of rus1f1kat0R's answer?

Comment: Problem is that...if i use the same image that i am going to download from, but store it statically, i.e. in my drawable folder, i am able to scroll without any issues...just when downloading remote image is screwing up everything..

Comment: His answer will verify that when your callback tries to load your image into a view, it loads to the proper view. Ex. you scroll the view off screen before its loaded.. that image will not be displayed until you scroll back. If you do not manage which view is supposed to contain the image you will end up displaying images out of order. .

Comment: The ViewPager class can be used by using the Android compatibility library [found here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) This is very easy to deploy with your application and I use it with most applications I write.

Comment: To elaborate on loading data incorrectly: Say you have 3 views A,B,C.. you start to load an image for A and scroll to C.. you do not specify which view should contain which URL.. when the image for A gets downloaded it will attempt to load it into a view. Since C will be using A's recycled container, the image for A will now be displayed in C.  If you tell the view which URL it should be display (ex. view.setTag("www.images.com/yourimage.jpg") ) and then checking it against which URL you have loaded you will prevent this from happening. I hope that makes sense

Comment: Yes i get it now, thank yo dymmeh. so his solution won't help my problem, but does bring up a separate issue i might need to worry about i guess?  i will makr ur response as an answer...but do u mind checking back in  case i have q's again?

Comment: i am currently using Android 3.1, ViewPager needs Android 4.0, does this mean if i use 4.0 some phone might not be able to use it becuase it is 4.0?

Comment: If it requires 4.0 and you wish to target 3.x you should use the compatibility library. You will alienate your 3.0 users if you switch to using 4.0

Answer (score 0):

At first you should note: Any AdapterView (Gallery, ListView etc) doesn't guarantee that each time getView() method is called it will pass the same View instance parameter. It only guarantees that each view will have the same type (see [Adapter.getIntemViewType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) method docs)

So, when you start image downloading you should only specify position of the element. Then after the image has been downloaded you should bind specified ImageView with downloaded image in Adapter.getView() method call.

Take a look to the ImageDownloader from the Android samples [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)

The other approach is to use WeakHashMap in order to contain map of adapter views to its positions. I can provide you with code samples if you need.

Comment: my image downloader is already based on the URL u provided...i am not sure by ur paragraph here "So, when you start image downloading you should only specify position of the element. Then after the image has been downloaded you should bind specified ImageView with downloaded image in Adapter.getView() method call."

Comment: I solved this by sticking with the Gallery view....my fix was to cache the image rather than downloading on demand